# How can i localize asp.net mvc application using a external assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I want to create a external DLL to store my .resx files.

I want to do this because i need to access these files from both presentation and business layers.

I have created a external project that contains the default and the es-Es resx files. i have marked it as PublicResXFileCodeGenerator to be able to access it from another DLL.

On my view I have this test

#### <%=localization.Common.title.ToString() %>

when I run the application I always get this error:

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "localization.Common.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "localization" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

I have read some this related to DLL signing... but I don't now if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the full path? This would help http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/fabioc/archive/2004/11/01/5030.aspx